# Edit valueForKey in NsMutableArray

Tags: ios7, nsmutablearray, key-value

I have a `NsMutableArray`. It has format as the below:

```
arrayTest:(
        {
        away = "Test 1";
        "time_start" = "20:30";
    },
        {
        away = "Test 2";
        "time_start" = "21:00";
    },
        {
        away = @"Test 3";
        "time_start" = "21:30";
    }
)
```

Can I edit or delete the value for 'away' in this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming here `arrayTest` is a NSMutableArray.

You can approach the first dictionary by `[arrayTest objectAtIndex:0]`.

Furthermore, to get the value for key`Test 1`, use `[[arrayTest objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Test 1"];`